# Reduce the size of links clickable area?

Tags: css, html

[image: That is my webpage nothing fancy i would like the word only to be clickable, at the moment the entire space the word falls on is clickable how do i reduce this?]
This is my css code what should i add to reduce the size of the link to where its just the word is a clickable link?

```
<style>


ul { 

list-style-type: none;

}

li {
    float: center;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: Black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: #6CCFFFb1;
}

.active {
    background-color: #6CCFFF ;
}
</style>
</head>
```

I've read some stuff but most code I've added hasn't worked or distorted the image of the webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Andis Place</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="stylesheet.css"/>

    </head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

        <body style="font-family:Courier New;" bgcolor="White"
    <head>
            <h1 style="color:Orange;"> <center>Welcome to Andis Place</center></h1>
        </head>
    </body>

    <body>
    <p style="font-size:15px;">Enjoy… </p>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>


<body>


<ul style="list-style-type:none">

  <li class="external-link">
          <a href="https://soundcloud.com/palomazee" target="_blank">Soundcloud</a>
        </li>
 <li class="external-link">
          <a href="" target="_blank">Shop</a>
        </li>
  <li class="external-link">
          <a href="" target="_blank">Photos</a>
        </li>
  <li class="external-link">
          <a href="" target="_blank">About Me</a>
        </li>
</ul>

</body>




<body>

</body>












</html>
```

This is my html code.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your HTML code as well.

Comment: added sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Move where you do your float.

Change your style from this:

```
ul { 
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    float: center;
}

li a {
:
:
```

To this:

```
ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
  float: center
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: Black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

:
:
```

Notice that I removed the "li" style altogether... also remove the style application on the UL tag itself. The CSS is sufficient.

Comment: yeah i tried it moves the links to the far left such as a list ignoring the text align

Comment: Could you please reword the question and perhaps explain your intent? Are you wanting to prevent invisible space from being clickable?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the invisible space not be clickable but rather only the word.

Comment: It would be helpful to tinker around W3Schools to understand how CSS works better. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you spend some more time working on some html and css basics while you are trying to fix this problem. I see a lot of errors in your markup and your styles that, although they may not be related to this particular issue, do make it harder to isolate just this behavior that you want to modify. The [Mozilla HTML introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction) is a good place to start.

Particularly you want to make sure that your HTML document is structured correctly. Only one `body` tag, no display content in the `head` tag, proper sets of opening and closing tags, etc. Focusing on these fundamentals makes debugging your code a lot easier (for you and others).

You are also trying to set a few css properties with values that don't actually exist, such as `float:center`.

As for this particular behavior you are seeing, this happens because it is the default behavior for block level elements to fill their container 100%. So your list items are stretching all the way across the screen, and you have set your anchor elements `display: block` as well, so they are stretching all the way across the screen. Try removing `display:block` and `text-align:center` from the anchor elements and just setting `text-align: center` on the li instead. (It is not necessary to set `display: block` on an `li` because that is it's default value.

[You can see a very simple example here in this codepen.](http://codepen.io/judahstevenson/pen/OXEbPZ)

Comment: thank you for the advice i will seek it to it seriously.

Comment: i changed what you advised and now the words aren't links and are close together as a regular list <ul style="list-style-type:none">
  
  <li style="text-align:center;>
          <a href="https://soundcloud.com/palomazee" target="_blank"> Soundcloud</a>
        </li>
 <li style="text-align:center; >
          <a href="" target="_blank">Shop</a>
        </li>
  <li style="text-align:center;>
         <a href="" target="_blank">Photos</a>
        </li>
  <li style="text-align:center;>
          <a href="" target="_blank">About Me</a>
        </li>
</ul>

Comment: I see what is happening now. In attempting to fix one "bug" or behavior you have accidentally introduced _another_ bug. In this case you have made a few very small typos. There is a typo on the style attribute inside the opening tag of each `li` element. You have written: 
`<li style="text-align:center; >` which is _missing_ it's closing double quote. It should be `<li style="text-align:center;">`. 

I was able to find this quickly because I copied your html into a text editor that supports syntax highlighting. It makes debugging like this a lot easier.

Comment: Would you mind if i ask what text editor? Im using TextWrangler at the moment.

Comment: There are a few that I like better but TextWrangler will work fine. Your choice of text editor really comes down to finding one that you like. If you are interested in checking out others I suggest you checkout [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) or [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Atom](https://atom.io/). If you are on a PC you can also check out [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). 

If I have helped you answer your question will you please mark my answer as the accepted answer? Hope that it was helpful.